# Restarting ODBC without restarting OS

Tags: c#, .net, db2, odbc

I have just entered an environment with a C# application interacting with a DB2 system. It appears as if the environment is connecting to DB2 via ODBC. At one point, the front-end quit unexpectedly and the transaction did not roll back in spite of the code being placed within a `using` block. Attempting to work with the table in DB2 returned a "FILE IN USE" error. I believe that the connection and associated pooling were likely held by ODBC and not the front-end process. Restarting the host rolled back the transaction successfully.

Is there a way to restart ODBC in the event that this happens again without restarting the host?

Comment: What platform (and version) of DB2?

Comment: ODBC is not a service to be stopped/started.  It is an API library that runs in your code.  If your application truly died (and not just the window gone), sounds like DB2 may not have recognized the lost connection and aborted the transaction.

Comment: During testing using C# and ODBC to Informix SE (a fairly old and not too often used standard engine of Informix), I will get an exception that never occurs after a reboot. I am searching for an application, non-kernel level tool that would find abandoned ODBC handles and free them. If I find anything like that, I'll post what I find.